# get current cpu usage with ruby or cli (NOT live like top)

Tags: ruby, macos, cpu-usage

I want to find a way that I can call a command or method, and get an int with the cpu usage the moment I called it. Not like top, where it keeps refreshing.

I am writing an app in MacRuby, so I can either use a cl command, or some ruby api.

any thoughts?

thanks

edit: can I somehow call top and get one frame of it in ruby? and from there I can get the percentage I need. Although I guess this way is not ideal..

kinda SOLVED: `top -l 1` on mac, `top -n 1` on linux. It runs top for just one frame.

Comment: Use `uptime` to get load average in one line, avoiding the overhead that `top` is producing.

Answer (score 0):

The `w` command gives a output which contains load average in the first line.

So try `w | head -1`

It's not an int, and not strictly "CPU usage", but it might be a start.

Comment: yes, but this is load avg of 1min. I can get that with the sys-cpu gem. I need a current cpu usage, like top, but just for one time.

Comment: You can run `top` with an option which makes it run once: `top -n 1` (as Andrew Grimm suggested)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether there's a command-line option for `top` to just give an instantaneous once-only output, and have you looked at `ps`?

Comment: About the top, yes.. I couldn't find anything.. and about ps, also nothing.. I googled and read the man for both.